# How to handle client-side routing received at the server with Flask?

Tags: python, url, flask

I plan an app with client-side routing with React. The server serves these:

```
/
/register/*
/login/*
/api/*
```

The client-side router "serves":

```
/proposals
/projects
```

The issue is with initial requests hits server. An initial request for say `/projects` hits server which responds with the static markup and client-side app.

---

How do I get Flask to serve the client-app when a request for a client-controlled route comes in? I can come up with the following, which involves declaring each client-route. Is there a better way?

```
app=...

app.configure_blueprint(api_blueprint)

@app.route("/projects/*")
@app.route("/proposals/*")
@app.route("/settings/*")
@app.route("/something/*")
def serve_app():
    serve_static_markup()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route("/<path:reqpath>")
def serve_app(reqpath):
    serve_static_markup()
```